# Elimination of array items based on a simple condition

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array containing information about boxes, their volume and weight.

```
$boxes = array('box1' => array('v' => 1.2, 'w' => 2.45), 
               'box2' => array('v' => 3.1, 'w' => 1.37), 
               'bigbox1' => array('v' => 6.2, 'w' => 5.45), 
               'box3' => array('v' => 2.15, 'w' => 2.94), 
               'smallbox1' => array('v' => 0.86, 'w' => 1.04), 
               'bigbox2' => array('v' => 11.3, 'w' => 10.9), ..);
```

I'd like to eliminate all boxes that have larger volume and lower weight at the same time than any other. E. g. box2 will be eliminated, because box1 is smaller and heavier.

Comment: You want to modify the $boyes array or just get the entry with smallest volume/weight?

Comment: yes, I want to modify that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is use 2 foreach loops.
For every box in the first foreach, you loop again over all the boxes and if your condition is met you can unset that from the `$boxes` array.

```
$boxes = array(
    'box1' => array('v' => 1.2, 'w' => 2.45),
    'box2' => array('v' => 3.1, 'w' => 1.37),
    'bigbox1' => array('v' => 6.2, 'w' => 5.45),
    'box3' => array('v' => 2.15, 'w' => 2.94),
    'smallbox1' => array('v' => 0.86, 'w' => 1.04),
    'bigbox2' => array('v' => 11.3, 'w' => 10.9)
);

foreach ($boxes as $key => $box) {
    foreach ($boxes as $b) {
        if (($box['v'] > $b['v']) && ($box['w'] < $b['w'])) {
            unset($boxes[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work as expected. Only 'box2' will get removed from $boxes, see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/22d3d97e47a1376653eddf0382a1d17851e96aa2